# Accessing AJP request data from a GWT servlet

Tags: apache, tomcat, gwt, shibboleth, mod-proxy-ajp

I'm trying to create a GWT application that implements Shibboleth-based authorization. Because eventually it should be served in "production mode", I chose to run the application using Tomcat7, however the client connects to Apache2 which then forwards the request to Tomcat via AJP (using `mod_proxy_ajp`).

The basic task, serving the application, works. However, I need to have access to the environment variables set by Shibboleth somehow. According to [the Shibboleth documentation](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPJavaInstall), environment variables will be forwarded to Tomcat if they are prefixed by `AJP_` (the prefix is then dropped), so I went ahead and configured Shibboleth in such a manner that it adds that prefix to all the environment variables it sets (this works, as I have confirmed using a PHP script that simply prints all the environment variables).

The trouble is that the environment variables aren't available as environment variables anymore when they reach Tomcat but are rather supposed to be served -- as the [`mod_proxy_ajp` documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html#env) phrases it -- as *AJP request attributes*.

Apparently, those kinds of attributes are supposed to be accessed using something like

```
getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("uid")
```

from within the servlet. Even though my PHP script lists an environment variable called `AJP_uid` however, the call above returns `null` while from what I understand it should return the same value that the environment variable `AJP_uid` has.

To be sure, I also tried the call above with `AJP_uid` instead of `uid` in case the prefix wasn't dropped for some reason, but with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried calling getAttribute on the request directly rather than the session?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer I had not, now I have and it worked flawlessly. Thanks so much!

Now, how do I go about marking this question as answered without depriving you of your credit?

Comment: Oh I don't really care, just accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ThomasBroyer mentioned, I can also call `getAttribute` on the `HttpServletRequest` object returned by `getThreadLocalRequest()` directly, which indeed did the trick for me:

```
getThreadLocalRequest().getAttribute("uid")
```

returns the appropriate value I expected. 
Thanks!